Reading parquet file from s3 changes Multipolygon column to binary
I am simply writing to s3 with a parquet format with this:
df.write.format("parquet").save(parquet_path)
using df.show(1) before inserting you can see my geo column has data like MULTIPOLYGON ((106.9343, 106.23232......)).
However, when reading this file with this:
df_loaded = spark.read.parquet("s3://path/")
df_loaded.show()
Then the geo column becomes a crazy long binary string like 0106000020E610000...
Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want to have to transform that column back into the right format before being able to use it.
Appreciate any help.
